# Shifted raster after processing

Tags: qgis

After I use an algorithm like "sink removal" my raster is shifted around 50 km to the south and west! Before this operation I needed to reproject the DEM from MGI / Austria GK West to WGS 84. Does anybody know the problem and can provide a solution?